# How to install LLNL VisIt on another distribution

Tags: visualization, opensuse, visit-llnl

community,

I'm a student doing CFD work with OpenFOAM & ParaView, but now I want to install [VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/simulation/computer-codes/visit/) due to project requirements. We use the **Opensuse Leap 15.2** distro to run simulations. When I go to the website and some distros appear except OpenSUSE. How can I install it without having to use a virtual machine?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If no pre-built executable exists for your particular distro, you can build it from the [source code](https://wci.llnl.gov/simulation/computer-codes/visit/source). I believe VisIt has some well [documented](https://visit-sphinx-github-user-manual.readthedocs.io/en/develop/gui_manual/Building/Basic_Usage.html) scripts helping the process.